# Give up the ownership of a stream/file

Tags: c#, mono, stream

I'm having a real strange issue while working with streams in mono.
I open a stream like this:

```
_stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

Where _stream of course is a FileStream. I added a dispose method for this class like that:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(!_disposed)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            _stream.Flush(true);
            _stream.Dispose();
            _items.Clear();
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Now i have this simple test:

```
[Test]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    SyncFileWriter s = new SyncFileWriter("file");
    s.Save("a", "b");
    s.Dispose();

    SyncFileWriter s2 = new SyncFileWriter("file");
    s2.Dispose();
}
```

But if fails with a IOException: Sharing violation. [edit]It looks like there was an error with monodevelop. Restarted it and now it fails everytime[/edit]

How to avoid this and close the stream properly?

Comment: This could be a simple timing problem (Win Filesystem can be slow). Test and maybe solve with `Thread.Sleep(10);` before reopening.

Comment: Is your system multi-threaded? non-deterministic makes me think about race conditions and whether there might be two of these in existance at the same time in different threads (eg ones spawned explicitly or via events)...

Comment: Hmmm. Even Thread.Sleep(1000) won't do any progress.
Of course my system is multi-hreaded, but it is a NUnit and and make sure that only one test at a time is executed. So this isn't the problem.

Comment: Have you set some breakpoints to make sure it's stepping through the `private` `Dispose` the way you expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was my fault. The SyncFileWriter is derived from a abstract class that checkes whether the file exist, or not. If not, it will initialize this file with some default things and that's why I did the following

```
File.Create(filename);
```

As you see, I create a file, but File.Create opens a stream and does not close it after leaving it's scope, whatever.
Now I do this:

```
Filestream f = File.Create(filename);
...
f.Dispose();
```

and everything is fine.

I think here lies also the problem for the first nondeterministic behavoir, because it does this only, when a parameter is null, and it is only null, when you create a new file.

Anyway, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but I guess this may help: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/UsingStatement.aspx

Comment: nope. I like to take the ownership of the file and use a stream for the whole time so I encapsulate the stream with a few other things in a own class. And what I try to archive is what I've said. I try to use a stream and close it afterwards ;)